# How to find rebase commits in git or github

Tags: git, github

How can I find commits in the central/master branch that were rebased? I thought it might be handy to be able to see commits that are the result of resolved merge conflicts during a rebase pull.

Example:

local branch ahead of master x amount of commits

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

conflicts found in file.txt

edit file

```
git add file.txt

git rebase --continue
```

rebased

```
git push
```

Now I want to look at the master branch and see which commits needed resolution before being pushed.

Comment: do you mean 'git log'?

Comment: no git log doesn't show any info about rebasing

Comment: is there parameters to add to git log to show info about merging rebasing?

Comment: try git 'reflog'

Comment: thats what i needed thanks

Comment: does github have reflog? I'd like to be able to see the info git reflog has in github

Comment: i've posted my answer, can you accept it?

Comment: actually I rarely using git reflog, so i'm not really sure if github have feature like reflog

Comment: What do you mean "need conflict resolution"? You have already resolved the conflict when you were editing the file in the previous steps.

Comment: Basically, all commits between the base (`origin` in your case) and `master` are rebased

Answer (score 3):

You can try `git reflog`, more reference https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog

Comment: `Reference logs, or "reflogs", record when the tips of branches and other references were updated in the _local_ repository. ` (from https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)
Be aware that reflog only shows your **local** reference log; it does not work on commits you pulled from a remote.